# Check if property exits in json

Tags: flutter, dart

so I'm having a little trouble with something.

I'm using an API, and if the property was null

```
{
  "Amount": {
    "Value": null,
    "Currency": "USD"
  }
}
```

This is how first started, and i was using `value = json["Amount"]["Value"] == null ? '' : json["Amount"]["Value"];`

```
{
  "Amount": {
    "Currency": "EUR"
  }
}
```

Now the value is gone, so how can i check it in my ".fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)" ?

Answer (score 1):

Make your value a **nullable type** def.

```
String? value = null;
value = json["Amount"]["Value"] == null ? '' : json["Amount"]["Value"];
```

also you can trim this at first

```
amount = json["Amount"];

value = json["Value"]?? "";
```

> or

```
value = json["Value"]??= "";
```

or read this property
[Flutter Property Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/isNotNull-constant.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check any key(Property) in Json(Map) whether it exist or not you can use this

```
bool contains = json['Amount']?.containsKey('Value') ?? false;
```

it will return true/false accordingly.

Comment: Fix your answer to

bool contains = json['Amount']?.containsKey('Value') ?? false;

for null-safe